# Only show active store groups within store selectors

Tags: magento-1.7, stores

I have a problem where the admin order creator shows a store selector when creating a new order or a customer, but it shows all the store (groups) we have in our store. Not all of these stores are active anymore

I would like to know if there's an easy way to make the store selector only show active stores as my employer isn't ready to delete the old stores yet. The site itself has a total of 9 stores in the backend, but only 4 are active on the frontend.

We're running Magento 1.7.

Answer (score 3):

There is one easy way to remove them from that list, which is removing the store views. If they won't be used anymore, removing them is your best solution. Not only because of the issue you're mentioning, but your indexes will be a lot faster with less store views.

If that's not a solution for you, you'll need to have a customisation for that part. You'll need to override several blocks and source models.